Why my test is getting reverted with `ERC20InsufficientAllowance` error?
I'm writing a Solidity test script using Foundry.
Here's the contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";

contract TestERC20Helper is ERC20Burnable {
    constructor(
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        uint256 initialSupply,
        address owner
    ) ERC20(name, symbol) {
        _mint(owner, initialSupply);
    }
}

Here's the test:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";

import "forge-std/Script.sol";
import "forge-std/console.sol";
import "forge-std/Test.sol";

import "@test/TestERC20Helper.t.sol";
//import "@test/TokenTest_2.sol";

contract TokenTest is Script, Test {
    address public constant EOAowner = address(0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720);
    address public constant EARNINGS_RECEIVER = address(0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266);

    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

    TestERC20Helper public erc20TestToken;

    function test_IERC20_safeTransferFrom() public {
        vm.startPrank(EOAowner);
        console.log("test_1 msg.sender:", msg.sender);
//        TokenTest_2 test2 = new TokenTest_2();
//        test2.test_change_msg_sender();
        console.log("test_1 msg.sender:", msg.sender);

        string memory token_name = "TestToken";
        string memory token_symbol = "TTK";
        erc20TestToken = new TestERC20Helper("TestToken", "TTK", 12345678910 * 1e18, EOAowner);
        console.log("test_1 erc20TestToken:", address(erc20TestToken));

        IERC20 tokenAddressErc20 = IERC20(address(erc20TestToken));

        vm.deal(address(EOAowner), 1111 ether);

        uint256 before_EOAowner_balance = tokenAddressErc20.balanceOf(EOAowner);
        console.log("test_1 before_EOAowner_balance :", before_EOAowner_balance);
        uint256 before_EARNINGS_RECEIVER_balance = tokenAddressErc20.balanceOf(EARNINGS_RECEIVER);
        console.log("test_1 before_EARNINGS_RECEIVER_balance :", before_EARNINGS_RECEIVER_balance);

        bool approveFlag = tokenAddressErc20.approve(EARNINGS_RECEIVER, 1 * 1e19);
        console.log("Allowance before approveFlag:", approveFlag);
        uint256 allowanceBefore = tokenAddressErc20.allowance(EOAowner, EARNINGS_RECEIVER);
        console.log("Allowance before transferFrom:", allowanceBefore);

        tokenAddressErc20.safeTransferFrom(EOAowner, EARNINGS_RECEIVER, 1 * 1e18);

        uint256 allowanceAfter = tokenAddressErc20.allowance(EOAowner, EARNINGS_RECEIVER);
        console.log("Allowance after transferFrom:", allowanceAfter);
        uint256 after_EOAowner_balance = tokenAddressErc20.balanceOf(EOAowner);
        console.log("test_1 after_EOAowner_balance :", after_EOAowner_balance);
        uint256 after_EARNINGS_RECEIVER_balance = tokenAddressErc20.balanceOf(EARNINGS_RECEIVER);
        console.log("test_1 after_EARNINGS_RECEIVER_balance :", after_EARNINGS_RECEIVER_balance);

        vm.stopPrank();
    }
}

I'm executing the test using this command:
forge test --match-path test/TokenTest.sol --match-test test_IERC20_safeTransferFrom -vvvvv

Here's the terminal output:
[⠆] Compiling...
No files changed, compilation skipped

Ran 1 test for test/TokenTest.sol:TokenTest
[FAIL. Reason: ERC20InsufficientAllowance(0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720, 0, 1000000000000000000 [1e18])] test_IERC20_safeTransferFrom() (gas: 564448)
Logs:
  test_1 msg.sender: 0x1804c8AB1F12E6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38
  test_1 msg.sender: 0x1804c8AB1F12E6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38
  test_1 erc20TestToken: 0x700b6A60ce7EaaEA56F065753d8dcB9653dbAD35
  test_1 before_EOAowner_balance : 12345678910000000000000000000
  test_1 before_EARNINGS_RECEIVER_balance : 0
  Allowance before approveFlag: true
  Allowance before transferFrom: 10000000000000000000

Traces:
  [564448] TokenTest::test_IERC20_safeTransferFrom()
    ├─ [0] VM::startPrank(0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720)
    │   └─ ← [Return]
    ├─ [0] console::log("test_1 msg.sender:", DefaultSender: [0x1804c8AB1F12E6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop]
    ├─ [0] console::log("test_1 msg.sender:", DefaultSender: [0x1804c8AB1F12E6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop]
    ├─ [481979] → new TestERC20Helper@0x700b6A60ce7EaaEA56F065753d8dcB9653dbAD35
    │   ├─ emit Transfer(from: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000, to: 0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720, value: 12345678910000000000000000000 [1.234e28])
    │   └─ ← [Return] 1947 bytes of code
    ├─ [0] console::log("test_1 erc20TestToken:", TestERC20Helper: [0x700b6A60ce7EaaEA56F065753d8dcB9653dbAD35]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop]
    ├─ [0] VM::deal(0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720, 1111000000000000000000 [1.111e21])
    │   └─ ← [Return]
    ├─ [552] TestERC20Helper::balanceOf(0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Return] 12345678910000000000000000000 [1.234e28]
    ├─ [0] console::log("test_1 before_EOAowner_balance :", 12345678910000000000000000000 [1.234e28]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop]
    ├─ [2552] TestERC20Helper::balanceOf(0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Return] 0
    ├─ [0] console::log("test_1 before_EARNINGS_RECEIVER_balance :", 0) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop]
    ├─ [24339] TestERC20Helper::approve(0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266, 10000000000000000000 [1e19])
    │   ├─ emit Approval(owner: 0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720, spender: 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266, value: 10000000000000000000 [1e19])
    │   └─ ← [Return] true
    ├─ [0] console::log("Allowance before approveFlag:", true) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop]
    ├─ [783] TestERC20Helper::allowance(0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720, 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Return] 10000000000000000000 [1e19]
    ├─ [0] console::log("Allowance before transferFrom:", 10000000000000000000 [1e19]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop]
    ├─ [2839] TestERC20Helper::transferFrom(0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720, 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266, 1000000000000000000 [1e18])
    │   └─ ← [Revert] ERC20InsufficientAllowance(0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720, 0, 1000000000000000000 [1e18])
    └─ ← [Revert] ERC20InsufficientAllowance(0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720, 0, 1000000000000000000 [1e18])

Suite result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 skipped; finished in 711.00µs (322.60µs CPU time)

Ran 1 test suite in 689.16ms (711.00µs CPU time): 0 tests passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped (1 total tests)

Failing tests:
Encountered 1 failing test in test/TokenTest.sol:TokenTest
[FAIL. Reason: ERC20InsufficientAllowance(0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720, 0, 1000000000000000000 [1e18])] test_IERC20_safeTransferFrom() (gas: 564448)

Encountered a total of 1 failing tests, 0 tests succeeded


As error says, it does not have sufficient allowance. Just make sure the caller has enough allowance to deduct tokens from sender wallet. You need to execute approve function to give allowance.

If you use safeTransfer instead of safeTransferFrom, then it would work fine, like:
tokenAddressErc20.safeTransfer(EARNINGS_RECEIVER, 1 * 1e18);

Because, in case of safeTransferFrom or transferFrom, the from address (i.e., EOAowner in your case) needs to be approved instead of the to address (i.e., EARNINGS_RECEIVER in your case), otherwise it would revert with the ERC20InsufficientAllowance custom error of ERC20 contract, as it's getting reverted in your case.
So, if you want to use safeTransferFrom, then you've to approve the from address (i.e., EOAowner) to spend tokens, before the safeTransferFrom call:
tokenAddressErc20.approve(EOAowner, 1 * 1e19);
tokenAddressErc20.safeTransferFrom(EOAowner, EARNINGS_RECEIVER, 1 * 1e18);

You can get rid of the approval of EARNINGS_RECEIVER as it's not the one spending tokens, it's just receiving them. So, you can remove this line:
b̶o̶o̶l̶ a̶p̶p̶r̶o̶v̶e̶F̶l̶a̶g̶ =̶ t̶o̶k̶e̶n̶A̶d̶d̶r̶e̶s̶s̶E̶r̶c̶2̶0̶.a̶p̶p̶r̶o̶v̶e̶(̶E̶A̶R̶N̶I̶N̶G̶S̶_̶R̶E̶C̶E̶I̶V̶E̶R̶, 1̶ *̶ 1̶e̶1̶9̶)̶;̶


thanks! You're absolutely right!

You’re welcome. Happy coding!
